# Someone can explain me what "ref()" function do?

Tags: vue.js, state

I don't understand the need to use "ref()" function when creating a state...
For example, the VueJS documentation show this:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

// global state, created in module scope
const globalCount = ref(1)

export function useCount() {
  // local state, created per-component
  const localCount = ref(1)

  return {
    globalCount,
    localCount
  }
}
```

Why not directly use this: "const globalCount = 1"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make the state `reactive`

Please check the Vue Docs:

- [​​Reactivity
  Fundamentals](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html)
- [Reactive Variables with
  ref()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref)

If you use

```
const globalCount = 1
```

then the `globalCount` is a constant, that is not only not reactive, but also cannot be changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

The ref() function returns a special reactive object. To access the value that ref() is tracking, we access the value property of the returned object:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const age = ref(0)

if(age.value < 18) {
  console.log("You are too young to drink. Get lost!")
} else {
  console.log("Have some ale mate!")
}
```